# When does Matrix Multiplication Exist?

Tags: linear-algebra

I wanted to make the title: 'When is Matrix Multiplication Well-Defined', but the software wouldn't let me.

If we have two matrices $A$ and $B$, then  $AB$ is well defined if and only if the number of columns of $A$ equals the number of rows of $B$.

Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly right.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

Comment: My pleasure. $\,$

Answer (score 1):

If $A=(a_{ij})$ and $B=(b_{jk})$ are matrices, with $1\leq i\leq n$, $1\leq j\leq p$, $1\leq k\leq q$ then the product $C=AB=(c_{ik})$ is the $(n\times q)$-matrix define by $c_{ik}=\sum_{j=1}^{p}a_{ij}b_{jk}$.

Here is an image from TeXample.net [image: TeXample.net]

Comment: Nice picture! You should share it on Wikipedia ;)